# How to make hybrid property from sqlalchemy ORM appear in return in asdict

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I have a model like below

```
class Invoice(Base):
    invoice_no = Column(String(64), nullable=False, unique=True)
    invoice_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    due_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    cgst_rate = Column(DecimalRate, nullable=False, default=CGST_RATE)
    sgst_rate = Column(DecimalRate, nullable=False, default=SGST_RATE)
```

I defined column property and hybrid property as below

```
    # column property
    total_amount = column_property(
        select(
            [func.round(func.coalesce(func.sum(InvoiceDetail.total_amount), 2))]
        ).where(InvoiceDetail.invoice_id == invoice_id)
    )
    cgst_amount = column_property((total_amount * cgst_rate))
    sgst_amount = column_property((total_amount * sgst_rate))
    @hybrid_property
    def grand_total(self):
        return self.total_amount + self.cgst_amount + self.sgst_amount

    @grand_total.expression
    def grand_total(cls):
        return func.sum(cls.total_amount,cls.cgst_amount,cls.sgst_amount)
```

When I return the sess.query object as **invoice.asdict()**....column_properties are coming properly but i don't get hybrid property.....any inputs on how to get hybrid property in response via asdic().